# Using Intents in PhoneGap/Cordova to call default maps app on ios and android platform

Tags: ios, cordova, android-intent, maps

I need some help implementing intents in PhoneGap/Cordova for a program that I have running on android and on ios. It's a driver application but I want to link it to the phones default maps app so that it can gps to it once the driver selects a destination. Something Uber like.

Comment: OK, what is your specific question?

Comment: I need some advice/examples of using intents in PhoneGap. If I selected a pressable button in my app and I wanted that button to take me to maps, what would that look like?

Comment: Further, the app will already have a map, a current location, and a lat lon. I just need to pass the info so the default maps app can gps to the destination.